# Structural break test, individual regressors

Tags: statistical-significance, change-point, stability

Say I have an equation

$y=\alpha_0+\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2$

and I'm testing for a structural break (SB) in one of the slope coefficients. How would I discriminate between the breaks. For example if over some period(s) there is a break associated with $\alpha_1$ and then later there is a break associated with $\alpha_2$?

I think usually SB tests focus on breaks in the intercept or some particular regressor for which there is a strong prior for a break. But is there a test that can somehow provide guidance, if you dont't have such information?